# Responsive images when using TinyMCE as a blog editor

Tags: image, responsive-design, tinymce, blogs

Good Morning.

I would like help with the TinyMCE editor that I am trying to integrate into my blog.

[I would like to remind you that I'm a beginner]

The problem I've been encountering is when viewing the blog on cell phones, as the images don't fit the screen, breaking the view.

view of the problem -

[image: view of the problem]

At the bottom, in gray, would be the page border.

In the search for solutions, I found this (but as you can see, it didn't solve the problem)

In tinymce.init:

```
image_dimensions: false,
  image_class_list: [
        {title: 'Responsive', value: 'img-responsive'}
    ]
```

can anybody help me?

Comment: When providing an example, it's best to provide a link to the page so the community can view the solution and provide a more accurate answer. If you can't provide a link to the page, solutions like Codepen (https://codepen.io/) or Tiny's TinyMCE Fiddle Tool (https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/) are a good way to share the implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will use it the next time I need it.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like this is your first post? Welcome!

My assumption is that the `img-responsive` CSS class isn't setup on your site properly. You probably need to setup the class on your site similar to:

```
.img-responsive {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Please have a look at this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/dallasclark/pen/JjXraxq) as an example. You can change the width of `small-element` in the CSS and the image will be responsive.

---

Alternatively, when you insert the image in TinyMCE, you can specify the image width as `100%`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I posted below how I managed to get around the problem for now ...
Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to adjust the img-responsive properties, but I have a bootstrap theme and I'm not sure where it is adjusting those properties.
After a more cautious review of the documentation, I was able to "resolve" this problem as follows:

In tinymce.init({...

```
style_formats: [
      {title: 'Imagem responsiva', selector: 'img', styles: {
          'width' : '100%',
          'height': '100%'
      }
    }
  ]
```

This created an option for formatting to be applied.

[Solution I got.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNGq3.jpg)

That way I was able to have responsive images without breaking the page layout when viewed on mobile devices.
Thanks to anyone who can help.